# add slideUp and slideDown to hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below to create a fade-in and fade-out effect on a hidden div on a FAQ page. Problem is, it makes the hidden div snap open and closed which is quite irritating. I'm not too hot on javascript and can't figure out how to get `slideUp` and `slideDown` into this, as I'd like it to also slide up and slide down. Is there any way to get a sliding function into this script? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                  
    $("a[name^='faq-']").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            if( $("#" + this.name).is(':hidden') ) {
                $("#" + this.name).fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $("#" + this.name).fadeOut('slow');
            }           
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you put an example of it on http://jsfiddle.net/? thanks :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Flukey. Sorry.

Comment: Are you just doing an accordion effect?  Might be easier to just style this to match http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with a small CSS tweak by using `visibility: hidden` to hide the divs instead of `display:none`.  This will reserve the space for the DIVs you are fading in & out.

You want to slide & fade at the same time?  Try using [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to set opacity to 0/1 and use height to max/0.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. `visibility:hidden` didn't seem to do the trick. Caused some other problems. I haven't played with `.animate()` before. Seems like some interesting things there. I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use fading rather than `slideUp/slideDown`, you can use `fadeTo(duration, opacity)` which will not make stuff jump as the space for the element is maintained.

If you want a plugin to combine slide and fade, maybe check out this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/combine-slide-and-fade-functions/